# 至多，最多，顶多 … what's the difference?

Tags: difference

Is there any difference in meaning? Usage or formailty or common colocations?

I know that 顶多 is more colloquial but I don't know if it's more common in normal speech and I don't know any other difference between these words. Same for 至少，最少，顶少。

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the occasion they were used.
“至多”is a formal expression.while“顶多”an oral expression.“最多”is something between them which can be used in different place，but not too formal or oral at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

最多 and 顶多 can mean ' to the largest extent'. For example, we say 我顶多/最多花点钱来搞定，but we don't usually say 我至多花点钱来搞定.

The three words are interchangeable when expressing ' to the largest number'. For example, 这件衣服至多/最多/顶多50元。

顶多 is more colloquial. 至多 is more formal, but it's not used as often as 最多/顶多. 最多 is common both colloquially and formally.